# Mass uploading Akeneo images on the community version

Tags: image, upload, akeneo

We recently updated to version 3.2 of the Akeneo PIM (Community version) and are now having major issues with uploading images. 
Somewhere along the way, they decided to change the import functions, and now I'm faced with an error:
Property "DispImage" expects a valid pathname as data, "/tmp/akeneo_batch_5e304c2f248eb//1/./Image/8000A000-1505162550.jpg" given.

In my excel import I have given the identifier and "./Image/8000A000-1505162550.jpg" as the image path, 
as the structure of the zip is:

zip
-excel file
-Image
-->8000A000-1505162550.jpg

I've gone through the forums, the documentation, and I'm still unsure as to how I can mass upload images to my products. 
Any help would be appreciated.